# Facebook Login OAuth Server 500 Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Got to love the Facebook API. It was working on Friday, come in to the office on Monday and it's now broken:

> The website encountered an error while retrieving
>
> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=351445771653053&client_id=351445771653053&display=popup&domain=braveclients.com&e2e=%7B%7D&locale=en_US&origin=1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D26%23cb%3Df18e457a4%26domain%3Dbraveclients.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fbraveclients.com%252Ff35e9d7fac%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df3e7627c54&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&scope=email%2C%20publish_actions&sdk=joey.
>
> It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
>
> Error code: 500

I've tried looking for any breaking changes that may have occured on the 1st of September but couldnt find anything, could it really be an internal Facebook error, or have they changed something?

- I'm using the JS SDK which is loaded directly from facebook.com with the following code: `FB.login(callback, {scope: "email, publish_actions"});`
- I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.2), but the JS handles the login button code.
- It seems to allow me to login on FireFox after I cleared my cache and reloaded the browser
- Chrome is still throwing the 500 error seen above, even in an Incognito Window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem: I had sandboxed the app, added myself as a developer but not accepted the developer request.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a new app.  Make sure it is set to public.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a bad/wrong scope.